# How to invoke PressCancel in the POReceipt screen

Tags: acumatica

In my POReceiptEntry extension, I wish to invoke Base.Actions.PressCancel.  But an error occurs.
  
Unable to cast object of type 'PX.Objects.PO.POReceipt' to type 'PX.Data.PXResult`2[PX.Objects.PO.POReceipt,PX.Objects.AP.Vendor]'.

It seems the cancel action is re-defined in the POReceptEntry graph, rather than the base graph object.  The goal is to discard any changes at the end of my routine and load the receipt record from the database.  Perhaps I should clear out any cached objects and assign the Current parameter, with the document?  I'm not sure.  Btw - I use version 6.10

Comment: should just be Base.Actions.PressCancel(). Can you include the code you are trying to run?

Comment: Can you post stack trace along with the error?

Comment: Likely this is the line in POReceiptEntry Cancel event handler that you hit: foreach (PXResult<POReceipt, Vendor> it in (new PXCancel<POReceipt>(this, "Cancel")).Press(adapter))

Comment: It looks like a bug from my point of view. I've created a case in Acumatica